# lwuit video component never stops

Tags: java-me, lwuit, video-component

i'm using lwuit videocomponent to play video.

```
import com.sun.lwuit.Button;
import com.sun.lwuit.Display;
import com.sun.lwuit.Font;
import com.sun.lwuit.Form;
import com.sun.lwuit.Image;
import com.sun.lwuit.VideoComponent;
import com.sun.lwuit.animations.CommonTransitions;
import com.sun.lwuit.events.ActionEvent;
import com.sun.lwuit.events.ActionListener;
import com.sun.lwuit.plaf.Border;
import com.sun.lwuit.table.TableLayout;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;

public class vtestMidlet extends MIDlet implements ActionListener{
    private Image back;
    public void startApp() {
        Display.init(this);
        loginform();
    }

    public void pauseApp() {
    }

    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
    }

  void loginform()
  {

       Form login=new Form();
       Button save;
       save=new Button("Save");
       login.addComponent(save);
login.getSelectedStyle().setBgColor(0xff0000);
login.getUnselectedStyle().setBgColor(0xff0000);
       save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
             videoform();
           }
       });

       login.setTransitionOutAnimator(CommonTransitions.createSlide(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_HORIZONTAL, false, 200));
       login.show();

  }

  void videoform()
  {
      final Form videoplayer;
      final VideoComponent vc;
      Button home;

      try{
        videoplayer=new Form();
        TableLayout layout2 = new TableLayout(10,1);
        videoplayer.setLayout(layout2);

        vc = VideoComponent.createVideoPeer("http://localhost/md.3gp");

        home=new Button("Home");
        vc.start();

        videoplayer.getUnselectedStyle().setBgImage(back);
        videoplayer.getSelectedStyle().setBgImage(back);
        home.getUnselectedStyle().setBgColor(0x4673aa);
        home.getSelectedStyle().setBgColor(0x4673aa);

        home.getUnselectedStyle().setFont(Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_PROPORTIONAL,Font.STYLE_PLAIN, Font.SIZE_MEDIUM));
        home.getSelectedStyle().setFont(Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_PROPORTIONAL,Font.STYLE_BOLD, Font.SIZE_MEDIUM));
        home.getUnselectedStyle().setFgColor(0xffffff);
        home.getSelectedStyle().setFgColor(0xffffff);
        home.getSelectedStyle().setBorder(Border.createEmpty());
        home.getUnselectedStyle().setBorder(Border.createEmpty());
        home.getSelectedStyle().setPadding(3, 3, 6, 6);
        home.getUnselectedStyle().setPadding(3, 3, 6, 6);

        videoplayer.addComponent(vc);
        videoplayer.addComponent(home);

        videoplayer.setTransitionOutAnimator(CommonTransitions.createSlide(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_HORIZONTAL, false, 200));

        home.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
              vc.stop();
              loginform();
            }
        });

        videoplayer.show();

      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

    }
}
```

My problem is when switch back to another Form (i.e loginform) from Form that displays video (i.e videoform ) , the video plays on top of the loginform. find the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because your video component is not stopping correctly.
Try adding:

```
VideoComponent vc;
Player player;
vc = VideoComponent.createVideoPeer("http://localhost/md.3gp");
player = (Player) vc.getNativePeer();
player.realize();
vc.start();
```

and in action listener:

```
player.stop();
vc.stop();
player.close();
loginform();
```